# How to install Edubuntu 11.10 from a DVD to an exisiting Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, edubuntu

I have downloaded Edubuntu 11.10 ISO and Created a DVD with it, but I already have a PC with Ubuntu 11.10 Running. How can I install Edubuntu from DVD?

My Ubuntu does not have an Internet connection. so I need to try to install it via the DVD.

Answer (score 3):

Boot into your Ubuntu OS normally, then insert the DVD into the drive.  Then add the DVD to your software center's "sources" list - it should be listed at the bottom and you just need to hit the checkbox to enable it:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

[image: screenshot of software sources window from the ubuntu wiki]

The final step would be to refresh the list of available packages, and install the Edubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: Hi ImaginaryRobots, i have tried that, it does not seem to pickup or refresh the list ,

Comment: does the DVD appear in the list of possible sources, or are you unable to select it?

Comment: the Dvd appears in " other software " the CDROM - line is there , but when i click close, and update list, i dont get anything there listed from the DVD- edubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Which DVD do you have ? You need the "alternate" DVD (not the live or desktop DVD). I am not sure if any of the other DVD have the packages to upgrade.

http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/11.10/release/

> Alternate install CD
>
> The alternate install CD allows you to perform certain specialist installations of Ubuntu. It provides for the following situations:
>
> - setting up automated deployments;
> - **upgrading from older installations without network access**;
> - LVM and/or RAID partitioning;
> - installs on systems with less than about 384MiB of RAM (although note that low-memory systems may not be able to run a full desktop environment reasonably).

Comment: i have downloaded ubuntu 11.10 . there is not "alternate" for X86 though. but i have downloaded DVD from Edubuntu website ... thats the dvd im using

Comment: OUCH !! I would file a bug report on that, I would think there would be a x86 alternate DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Load the DVD in the drive and reboot. If the doesn't boot to your DVD but instead loads your normal Ubuntu desktop, then check the boot order settings in your BIOS to ensure that the DVD drive is set to boot before the HDD (hard disk drive).

Comment: hay there, no if i boot from DVD it tells me to install along side ubuntu or re format HDD

Comment: Install alongside if you want to test Edubuntu. If you reformat the HDD you will lose your existing Ubuntu installation and all your data - in such a case, take a backup, ** before formatting **, of your home folder plus any other files you cannot afford to lose.